# 301 redirect entire domain to corresponding URL on new domain - EXCEPT for one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

As the title says, I am migrating a website from `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`.  I currently have an htaccess 301 redirect in place in the web root of `olddomain.com` as follows that redirects any request to `olddomain.com/any/url` to the same corresponding url on `newdomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My question is, how can I modify this rewrite rule to exclude ONE specific directory?  `olddomain.com/downloads` will continue to serve as a file mirror, so I need to exclude `olddomain.com/downloads` (and all its subdirectories such as `/releases`, etc) from the original site-wide 301 redirect such that any request to a URL on `olddomain.com` is redirected to the corresponding URL on `newdomain.com` with the exception of any request for a file or directory that lives inside `olddomain.com/download`.

**EDIT** As mentioned in the comments below, I also need to exclude `olddomain.com/getlatest.php` from the redirect, since it generates a download link that relies on parsing the server directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative condition in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(downloads(/.*)?|getlatest\.php)$ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!  One more question: how can I also exclude olddomain.com/getlatest.php in the same way? (It's a PHP script that generates a download link to the most recent build and does not work from newdomain.com since it parses the olddomain.com directory structure to generate the link)

Comment: (i'll mark this as answer if you can help me out with that last bit)